# bootstrap navbar button dropdown wont disappear on click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Having a little trouble with the dropdown list on my bootstrap site.

[Here](http://www.tokoloshdesign.com/testbed/ryal/index.html)

when the navbar has collapsed to the toggleable button and i click on it, it displays the dropdown list correctly, but when I click a link and it goes to the correct section the dropdown list does not disappear like i would like it to.

Its my first bootstrap site and im a newbie webdev... so in spite of scouring the bootstrap site... i have come away empty.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

Set one `id` to that toggle **button**, and set common `class` name to that **link button** in the navbar, and write the condition like when clicking the link button , the button toggle also clicked together when the nav is in collapsed state like below

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/idr8ej8hOV)

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button id="btnCollapse" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a class="a" href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a class="a" href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a class="a" href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a class="a" href="#">Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```

SCRIPT:

```
 $(".a").click(function () {
            if ($("#btnCollapse").css('display')!='none')
            $("#btnCollapse").click();
        });
```

Comment: Thank you kindly good sir, forgive me but this is my first bootstrap site and im not sure what you mean... add the id btnCollapse to the button.... add the script.... it doesnt work....thats probably becuuse i dont know what you mean by set common class name to that link button. soory i be a noob :(

Comment: see my code and demo , I set the id="btnCollapse" to <button> and class="a" to <a> and some script

Comment: You are a Legend :D Thank you, I cant believe I missed that... and it works beautifully. guess i better get back to finishing the Javascript version of the course.